# How to select only the most recent timestamp?

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group, sql-server-2016

If I am performing an inner join on multiple tables, how do I ensure that the result set will only contain the most recent timestamp. E.g.

```
SELECT
  e.customer_id AS customer_id,
  e.event_id AS event_id,
  #MOST RECENT TIMESTAMP from car.updated_on, motorcycle.updated_on or walkc.updated_on
FROM
  event_table AS e
  INNER JOIN car AS c ON e.customer_id = c.customer_id
  INNER JOIN motorcycle AS m ON e.customer_id = m.customer_id
  INNER JOIN walk AS w ON e.customer_id = w.customer_id
WHERE
  e.event_id = c.event_id
  AND e.event_id = m.event_id
  AND e.event_id = w.event_id
```

I have a single table which records all events that occur, I only want to pull the most recent timestamp regardless of the event type for all customers that are in all three events (car, motorcycle or walk).

Sample data:

**event**

| customer_id | event_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 101 |
| 3 | 102 |
| 4 | 103 |
| 5 | 104 |
| 6 | 105 |
| 7 | 106 |
| 8 | 107 |
| 9 | 108 |
| 10 | 109 |

**car**

| customer_id | event_id | car_id | updated_on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 1 | 2021-07-23 10:09:05 |
| 2 | 101 | 1 | 2021-07-23 10:09:05 |
| 3 | 102 | 1 | 2021-07-23 10:09:05 |
| 4 | 103 | 1 | 2021-07-23 10:09:05 |
| 5 | 104 | 1 | 2021-07-23 10:09:05 |
| 6 | 105 | 1 | 2021-07-23 10:09:05 |
| 7 | 106 | 1 | 2021-07-23 10:09:05 |
| 8 | 107 | 1 | 2021-07-23 10:09:05 |
| 9 | 108 | 1 | 2021-07-23 10:09:05 |
| 10 | 109 | 1 | 2021-07-23 10:09:05 |

**motorcycle**

| customer_id | event_id | motorcycle_id | updated_on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 1 | 2021-07-23 10:09:00 |
| 2 | 101 | 1 | 2021-07-23 10:09:00 |
| 3 | 102 | 1 | 2021-07-23 10:09:00 |
| 4 | 103 | 1 | 2021-07-23 10:09:00 |
| 5 | 104 | 1 | 2021-07-23 10:09:10 |
| 6 | 105 | 1 | 2021-07-23 10:09:10 |
| 7 | 106 | 1 | 2021-07-23 10:09:00 |
| 8 | 107 | 1 | 2021-07-23 10:09:00 |

**walk**

| customer_id | event_id | walk_id | updated_on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 1 | 2021-07-23 10:09:00 |
| 2 | 101 | 1 | 2021-07-23 10:09:00 |
| 3 | 102 | 1 | 2021-07-23 10:09:00 |
| 4 | 103 | 1 | 2021-07-23 10:09:00 |
| 5 | 104 | 1 | 2021-07-23 10:09:00 |
| 6 | 105 | 1 | 2021-07-23 10:09:00 |
| 7 | 106 | 1 | 2021-07-23 10:09:00 |
| 8 | 107 | 1 | 2021-07-23 10:09:15 |
| 9 | 108 | 1 | 2021-07-23 10:09:15 |

**Desired Result:**

| customer_id | event_id | updated_on | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 2021-07-23 10:09:05 | TS from car |
| 2 | 101 | 2021-07-23 10:09:05 | TS from car |
| 3 | 102 | 2021-07-23 10:09:05 | TS from car |
| 4 | 103 | 2021-07-23 10:09:05 | TS from car |
| 5 | 104 | 2021-07-23 10:09:10 | TS from motorcycle |
| 6 | 105 | 2021-07-23 10:09:10 | TS from motorcycle |
| 7 | 106 | 2021-07-23 10:09:15 | TS from walk |
| 8 | 107 | 2021-07-23 10:09:15 | TS from walk |

I do not need the `comment` in the final result set, i added it for explanation purposes only. Effectively, i don't care what the event was. All i care about is the `INNER JOIN` of the four tables; so there should only be 8 records at most and I only want the timestamp value that is the most recent (highest). The `customer_id` and `event_id` need to match for all the `INNER JOINS`.

E.g: `customer_id = 1` and `event_id = 100`; this exists in all 4 tables. It has three values for `updated_on` (from each: car, motorcycle and walk). I want the `MAX(2021-07-23 10:09:05, 2021-07-23 10:09:00, 2021-07-23 10:09:00)`; `MAX(car.updated_on, motorcyle.updated_on, walk.updated_on)`.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT**: I got the desired result working in two queries. Hoping to optimize into a single query.

1. Get only the `UNIQUE` records between the three tables and store them in another location called `event_joined`. This table is fully overwritten each time and not just appended to.

```
SELECT
  e.customer_id AS customer_id,
  e.event_id AS event_id,
FROM
  event_table AS e
  INNER JOIN car AS c ON e.customer_id = c.customer_id
  INNER JOIN motorcycle AS m ON e.customer_id = m.customer_id
  INNER JOIN walk AS w ON e.customer_id = w.customer_id
WHERE
  e.event_id = c.event_id
  AND e.event_id = m.event_id
  AND e.event_id = w.event_id
```

2. Prior to doing a `UNION`, we know that all three tables will have the same row count because we previously joined them for matching records only. Now we simply `GROUP BY` and get the `MAX` (most recent) timestamp.

```
SELECT event_temp.customer_id, event_temp.event_id, MAX(event_temp.updated_on) AS updated_on
FROM (
  SELECT customer_id, event_id, updated_on FROM car AS c INNER JOIN event_joined AS ej ON e.customer_id = c.customer_id AND e.event_id = c.event_id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT customer_id, event_id, updated_on FROM motorcycle AS m INNER JOIN event_joined AS ej ON e.customer_id = c.customer_id AND e.event_id = c.event_id
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT customer_id, event_id, updated_on FROM walk AS w INNER JOIN event_joined AS ej ON e.customer_id = c.customer_id AND e.event_id = c.event_id
) AS event_temp
GROUP BY event_temp.customer_id, event_temp.event_id;
```

Is there any way to optimize this into a single query? Thanks.

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: Sorry to bug you, any idea what i can use for table formatting? It looks good in preview but when i press save it doesn't generate the table correctly.

Comment: I updated it, I hope screenshots are okay. I couldn't figure out the markdown. Looks like a bug with stack :(

Comment: Why do the car, motorcycle, and walk tables have a customer id when the event table they are linked to already has a customer ID? Your tab,e structure does not make sense. Also, how relevant is this messy table structure to your actual question? Try to pare this down to the bare minimum.

Comment: Unfortunate technical limitation on legacy system I can't upgrade otherwise i'd have normalized the whole mess. Effectively, I know that i need to do 4 `INNER JOINS` which is fine. I just need to get the most recent `TIMESTAMP` from the other 3 tables.

Comment: "an appropriate database tag" doesn't mean adding the tag `database`. Gordon referred to adding a tag that specifies the actual database _product_ you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: Did not realize, my bad. I updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go for simple query with CROSS APPLY as given below:

```sql
SELECT
  e.customer_id AS customer_id,
  e.event_id AS event_id,
  max(t.updated_On)
FROM
  event_table AS e
  INNER JOIN car AS c ON e.customer_id = c.customer_id and e.event_id = c.event_id
  INNER JOIN motorcycle AS m ON e.customer_id = m.customer_id and e.event_id = m.event_id
  INNER JOIN walk AS w ON e.customer_id = w.customer_id and e.event_id = w.event_id
  CROSS APPLY (values (c.updated_On),(m.updated_On),(w.updated_On)) as t(updated_On)
GROUP BY e.customer_id,
  e.event_id
```

**Sample data and working solution**

```sql
declare @event table(cust_id int, event_id int)
declare @car table(cust_id int, event_id int, updated_on datetime)
declare @walk table(cust_id int, event_id int, updated_on datetime)

insert into @event values (1, 100)
insert into @car values (1,100, '2020-01-01')
insert into @walk values(1,100, '2020-02-01')

SELECT
  e.cust_id AS customer_id,
  e.event_id AS event_id,
  max(t.updatedON)  as recent_timestamp
FROM
  @event AS e
  INNER JOIN @car AS c ON e.cust_id = c.cust_id and e.event_id = c.event_id
  INNER JOIN @walk AS w ON e.cust_id = w.cust_id and e.event_id = w.event_id
  CROSS APPLY (values(c.updated_On),(w.updated_on)) as t(updatedOn)
  group by e.cust_id, e.event_id
```

| customer_id | event_id | recent_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 2020-02-01 00:00:00.000 |

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. The values(c.updated_On table has a multi-part specification. This is not allowed. Is the error message i get. No futher details when trying to run your query.

Comment: @Jordan, ideally, it should work. I tested it and it worked fine

Comment: I confirmed it does run on regular SQL Server 2016, unfortunately the software i use limited the usage of some of the functionality for some strange reason. Your solution did give me an idea on how to do it without Cross Apply, Thanks.